# CRON session entries in logs

Tags: security, logs, access-control

I'm having this in my RaspberryPi /var/log file

```
Feb 26 21:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[15182]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 26 21:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[15182]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 26 21:39:01 raspberrypi CRON[15189]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 26 21:39:01 raspberrypi CRON[15189]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

in fact... my log file is full of this CRON session opened and closed.
Is this a security issue? someone is trying to access my raspberry pi?

if so .. what can I do?
Is there any tool that I can install to see from what IP address is coming the attack?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an issue. Cron is a system processes that runs things at times. (every hour etc.) It's running stuff as root. That is normal.